# R.dll file missing

Tags: r, rserve

I have installed R(x64) in my system with extra libraries.
I have setup the path in environment variables for both R as well as Rserve(one of the few extra library that was downloaded)
No when I open up my command prompt and enter R, it accepts the command but when I enter Rserve to check, it shows "R.dll is missing".
I have tried reinstalling the R package but the same error pops up every time.

Answer (score 3):

The reason which cause the problem is that **Windows** can not locate `R.dll`.

Try add `R.dll` to your system path, two steps may work out:

1. create system variable `R_HOME`, e.g. `R_HOME = D:\R\R-3.2.5\bin;`
2. add `R.dll` to `path`: `path = %R_HOME%\x64;%OTHER_DEPENDENCIES%;`