# Import the output of an R script with Python

Tags: python, r, python-requests, subprocess, method-call

my first post in this stackoverflow! :)

I am trying to import a table (output of an R script) using Python.
This would be very helpful to avoid to translate a huge script designing a complex data.table in R.

Righ now I know how to call the R script with Python using the following code:

```
import os 
import subprocess
 
#Launch selected script
command = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/bin/x64/Rscript.exe'
path2script = 'C:/mypath/myscript.R'
cmd = [command, path2script]
a = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

But then I dont know how to use the table, output of the R code, using my Python script. Would you have any idea?

Many thanks

EDIT:

I tried the solution from @punter below

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(['/command/to/run', '/other/parameters'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    table = proc.stdout.read()
```

But then the table as a strange format  like this: (it is a subset)

```
A\r\n COL1 COL2 COL3\r\n 1: 2015-06-17 05:19 NA <NA>\r\n 2: 2015-06-17 05:19 NA <NA>\r\n 3: 2015-06-17 05:19 NA <NA>\r\n 4: 2015-06-17 05:19 NA <NA>\r\n 5: 2015-06-17 05:19:29 NA <NA>\r\n
```

and when I try the code below I get all the content in the column names

```
s=str(table) 
data = StringIO(s) 
df=pd.read_csv(data)
```

[0 rows x 111 columns]

EDIT NUMBER 2

trying with this "ISO-8859-1" in str like str(table, "ISO-8859-1") seems to be working and I could notice that I had more than one table in my script.
I am rerunning everything in a clean way I hope it will work! :)

Comment: Can you save the output from the R script to file that you then open later in the Python code?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I could it it indeed but my table is quite big (millions of lines) so I would like to see if there are any other options before to go for this.

Comment: Do you have any quick ways to generate large tables in R. I am new to R and cannot find any large table to print in order to test the solution. It would be great if you could answer the above question. Meanwhile check out my solution. The solution probably wont work as required for large tables.

Comment: Hello @punter147, Thanks a lot. You can use this code to generate big tables: test <- as.data.table(matrix(rexp(200000000, rate=.1), ncol=20)). I am very curious about your solution it would be awesome if it works

Comment: And thank you for the script that you provided I am trying with my R code (it takes around 30 minutes to run it)

Comment: Pleasure. Glad that the script is working. However, as you pointed out, I think the script takes a lot of time. I am trying to make it asynchronous, so that other tasks can be performed meanwhile the table is loading. Also, thanks a lot for the R script. This will help a lot.

Comment: Actually I had to rerun it, the R script takes 30 minutes but thepython script with your code is still running since 2 hours I dont know if it works (would be awesome) but I will let you know. No problem for the R script

Comment: Finally it did not work it is running non stop but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

For any process in general, the stdout can be captured as follows:

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(['/command/to/run', '/other/parameters'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    table = proc.stdout.read()
```

this is a blocking call, this means that the execution will halt at table = proc.stdout.read().

**Note**
The above code may not work as required for large tables, as the process will block at the line shown above for a very long time.

Comment: THank you I could run it but then my output is not a table but has a strange format like this: A\r\n          COL1 COL2              COL3\r\n       1:       2015-06-17 05:19           NA                 <NA>\r\n       2:       2015-06-17 05:19          NA                 <NA>\r\n       3:       2015-06-17 05:19           NA                 <NA>\r\n       4:       2015-06-17 05:19           NA                 <NA>\r\n       5:       2015-06-17 05:19:29           NA                 <NA>\r\n      ---    any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: I tried to run the code below but then I get my input like this 
[0 rows x 111 columns]                                      
s=str(table)
data = StringIO(s) 
df=pd.read_csv(data)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the r2py interface. This allows you to make conversions from R to pandas objects: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/r_interface.html.

You can store your table in an RData file and then load it into python.

Comment: Well the question is explicitly asking for ideas and without any working examples I guess this is the best you can do...

Comment: Hello @pieterbons thanks a lot for your answer, I also tried to use rpy2 but I get an error message when running the "import rpy2" because it could not access R.dlll

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248680/r-dll-file-missing

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting R script to use `write.csv()` as last line *without* a file name to dump data to console. This will allow string values to be quoted. Then in Python, use `subprocess.Popen` to receive output with byte handling for migration into Pandas data frame.

**R**

```r
...

write.csv(my_r_df, file="", row.names=FALSE)
```

**Python**

```py
import subprocess
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
 
# RUN R SCRIPT
command = r'C:\Path\To\Rscript.exe'
path2script = r'C:\Path\To\R\Code.R'

a = subprocess.Popen([command, path2script], 
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                      
output, error = a.communicate()

# IMPORT PANDAS DATA FRAME
my_pandas_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(output.decode('utf-8')))

my_pandas_df
```

Of course, too, you can have R simply write data to .csv and then import into Pandas.

Comment: Thank you I am trying this now

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the R dataframe to the clipboard and then load it to Pandas using read from clipboard. Here is how it works.

Use this code to copy a R dataframe to clipboard, then go to Jupyter and use pd.read_clipboard().

```
# If you are on Windows, use:
# R-Studio
write.table(df, "clipboard", sep="\t", col.names=TRUE)

# Jupyter
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\t")
```

---

```
# On Mac, use:
# R-Studio
clip <- pipe("pbcopy", "w")                       
write.table(df, file=clip)                               
close(clip)

# Jupyter Notebook
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you I tried this but I got a table with only few rows and fill only with NA, I do not know why